# Laravel 4 Queue:listen times out

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, symfony-components

I ran `php artisan queue:listen` and after about 27 minutes, it stops processing any more jobs. In my error log, I see the error:

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'The process timed out.' in /var/www/l4site/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php:413
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/l4site/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php(201): Symfony\Component\Process\Process->wait(NULL)
#1 /var/www/l4site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Listener.php(63): Symfony\Component\Process\Process->run()
#2 /var/www/l4site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Listener.php(50): Illuminate\Queue\Listener->runProcess(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Process), 128)
#3 /var/www/l4site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/ListenCommand.php(69): Illuminate\Queue\Listener->listen(NULL, 'default', 0, 128, 60)
#4 /var/www/l4site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(108): Illuminate\Queue\Console\ListenCommand->fire()
#5 /var/www/l4site/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(240): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#6 /var/www/l4site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(96): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#7 /var/www/l4site/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(193): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#8 /var/www/l4site/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(106): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#9 /var/www/l4site/artisan(59): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#10 {main}
```

[image]

Is this a bug? I don't think the listener is supposed to time out!

---

### Update

A second run of the listener timed out after 3 hours. I'm running Laravel 4 on nginx with php-fgm.

Comment: When was the last time you ran `composer update`?  It might have been fixed since you last tried.

Comment: @PhillSparks I just did a `composer update` and the problem persists. The function called by the worker does a `shell_exec()`. Another listener's worker that does not call `shell_exec()` does not have this timeout problem. Wonder if its due to `shell_exec()`...

Answer (score 9):

Regardless of how long you have it set to it will eventually run out of memory or timeout. You can use supervisor to keep it running. It is really simple to use.

**First Install** it:

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

or use a method listed on their site like easy_install `http://supervisord.org/installing.html`

**Now add a config file** for supervisor. Open `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/queue.conf` (or whatever you want to name the file but put it in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/`) and add:

```
[program:queue]
command=php artisan queue:listen
directory=/var/www/laravel
stdout_logfile=/var/www/laravel/app/storage/logs/supervisor_queue_listener.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

Explanation of the above: `program:_____` is how we name what is run. We will reference that later. `command` is the command you want to run. `directory` is where it should be run. In my case I am in a project called "laravel". `stdout_logfile` is the file where you want to redirect he stdout that is received from the command. `redirect_stderr` is set to true to direct all of the errors to the same log specified at `stdout_logfile` you can also set these to go to their own log file.

**Open supervisor controller**:

```
sudo supervisorctl
```

**Read the contents of the `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/`** directory: (while still in supervisorctrl)

```
reread
```

**Add the queue program to supervisor**:

```
add queue
```

That's it. Now it should be running. If you have erros look in your log file to see what is wrong.

Once you restart your server you will have to start supervisor again with `sudo service supervisor start`.

[Laracasts covers Supervisor](https://laracasts.com/lessons/supervise-this) really well. If you aren't subscribed to Laracasts I highly recommend it.

Comment: This is the best answer. Setting --timeout=0 is a bad idea. Jobs should timeout or be broken into chunks for processing so each job can be handled in a small amount of time. Use supervisor to make sure your jobs are always running and then handle the timeout exceptions as they come so you know where you need to optimize your jobs.

Answer (score 7):

`queue:listen` in Laravel 4 has a `--timeout` option. If you want an unlimited timeout you should set the --timeout option to 0.

```
./artisan queue:listen --timeout=0
```

Comment: this is a bad idea since it will result invisible loops that suck up your cpu and memory

Answer (score 3):

just run  COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=4000 php artisan queue:listen

Comment: COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=4000 composer create-project laravel/laravel

worked for me. thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Nor the process either the artisan is timing out. its the process wrapper.
Symfony\Component\Process\Process Class is used to run the whatever process (in my case Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\Snappy\LoggableGenerator the bundle that prints PDFs with wkhtmltoPDF is conidering that wkhtmltoPDF timed out just because I'm rendering a PDF with 11000 pages, it just needs more time)

Its nothing to do with php.ini's max_execution_time = XXX (as its an exception thrown by Symfony Process instance with a confusing message)

You have to manage to get through the object relations to call

```
Symfony\Component\Process\Process->setTimeout(null)
```

This solves de problem. In my case:

```
    $knp = $this->getContainer()->get('knp_snappy.pdf');
    /* @var $knp \Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\Snappy\LoggableGenerator */
    $knp->getInternalGenerator()->setTimeout(null);
    $pdf = $knp->getOutputFromHtml($this->view, $printOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there is a time limit. 
Change the time limit and problem solved.
set_time_limit(howmanysecondsyouneed)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: I restarted the queue listener and now it's been running fine for over an hour... shouldn't Laravel remove the time limit by itself since this is supposed to be a queue listener with a `while(true)` infinite loop?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel, but as you see that solved your time limit problem, because by default there is a time limit

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the listener is timing out, I think that the process it's trying to run is timing out.  That exception comes from [Symfony\Component\Process](https://github.com/symfony/Process/blob/master/Process.php#L320).  Unfortunately the process code itself is a little over my head for today.

Comment: Setting `set_time_limit(0)` in the function the worker calls does not prevent the error... wonder what's causing it

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked like a charm. It's been running overnight now(more than 12hours).

```
php artisan queue:listen --timeout=0
```

Thanks to timgws answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org) to ensure your process keeps on running. With supervisord installed in the event that your process dies for any reason, this daemon will start it back up again.The company I work for has been using it in conjunction with queue:listen for a while now.